# DateField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am having an issue with the DateField field in Django. I see "midnight" getting attached to the field in the admin page. And this only shows in my E3, not E1.

E3:

[image: E3]

E1:

[image: E1]

models.py:

```
class BackoutLogFile(models.Model):

    log_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=800, verbose_name='Device Name',default='sampledevice')
    log_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='User ID')
    log_user_email = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='User Email',default='admin')
    change_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Change Number',default='CHG00000000')
    #log_capture_date = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Event Date')
    log_capture_date = models.DateField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Event Date',auto_now=True)
    log_details = models.TextField(verbose_name='Log Details')
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Backout Logs'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Backout Logs'

    def __unicode__(self):

        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.device_name,self.log_user_id,self.log_user_email,self.change_number,self.log_capture_date,self.log_details)
```

place where obj is saved:

```
obj=BackoutLogFile(log_user_id=user,device_name=spine_backout_list_name[i],log_user_email=request.user.email,change_number=changeRequestNumber,log_details=event_data)
obj.save()
```

Comment: Attached the models.py and the place where I save the data

Comment: When a date is displayed as a datetime, by default it sets the time portion to `00:00:00`, or midnight. It looks like your view is displaying a datetime, while the object it's displaying is simply a date.

Comment: In my views.py, I am not even inputting that field, it assumes the default from models.py which is auto_now=True @MattDMo

Comment: Also why would it work in E1 one way and differently in E3 ? Is it just the way the migrations were applied? Because we do more testing in E1.

Comment: I'm not a Django expert, so I can't answer that, sorry, I just happened to know how the date<->datetime thing works in Python in general. Are you trying to get the actual timestamp of when the object was created? If so, [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield) may be an option.

Comment: For a DateField, it would return only the date as in E1. Please check whether you have DateTimeField in E3, this will be the only possibility or you would have defined that in your admin.py

Comment: The code is same, but we recently upgraded our E1 postgresql to v13, in E3 its still v11